# Can we replace "textarea" shift+enter behavior with ctrl+enter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keyboard-events

I just want line break in textarea when i press shift+enter. Can i do same with Ctrl+enter? please
here is my code which inovke on keypress:

```
  keypress: function (editor, event) {
          $(".emojionearea, .emojionearea.form-control").css("overflow","hidden");
          if (event.keyCode == 13 && !event.shiftKey) { 
                event.preventDefault();  
                submitMessage(); 
                return true; 
            } 

            function submitMessage() { 
                $("#message_submits").trigger("click");
            }

          if(event.which == 10){
                                                    //// when press Ctrl+enter
             console.log(event.originalEvent);
             return true;
           }

        }
```